# Chrome tutorials - options page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on my first chrome extension.

I followed this article http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html to base my options page off of.  So when I reload my extension, and I click "options" I see the page correctly, but when I change an options and save it, the setting is not saved. As far as the setup goes it's very basic right now, just used the getting started tutorial.  I am not sure why this isn't working and not sure where to start. Thank you. Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: We need to see the code (your code) before we can tell you what is wrong. "It doesn't work" isn't nearly enough information to begin fixing it.

Comment: Look at the tutorial page I posted. That right there is my code, really that's it.

Comment: Ok here's my problem maybe someone can help me understand it.

The getting started tutorial manifest.json file includes this `"manifest_version": 2`, however if I remove the manifest version, it works.

Comment: May be because the missing comma, may be because you aren't using Chrome 18+.  manifest_version 2 works only con Chrome 18+ and doesn't work on Chrome 17-.  manifest_version 2 will be mandatory in the near future.  Wrong time to start with extensions!

Comment: Ok it has nothing to do with a missing coma (because it's not missing) obviously it would throw and error and not even load the extension if the json is invalid...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"manifest_version": 2` forbids embedded scripts. Move all of the JavaScript to `options.js` and load it that way.

Comment: This is the error message I get 'Refused to execute inline event handler because of Content-Security-Policy.'

Comment: As I said you have to move all of you JS to a JS file.

Comment: I did that. I moved all the JS from the options.html to options.js but, it made no difference. I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: It probably doesn't work because of `onclick="save_options()"` Check out these docs. They cover how to fix it. https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1

Comment: Thanks abraham, I was pulled off this project for awhile to finish up some other work but I'm back. Your solution was correct.

Comment: Also make sure your "storage" permissions are declared in your manifest file: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Otherwise, when you click the "Save" button, the options will not actually get saved and will return to the default options if the options page is loaded at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "storage" permission in manifest.json helps:

```
...
"permissions": [
   "storage"
]
```